# Problemas SDK no Fedora Workstation 24

Tags: java, android, ionic, mobile, sdk

A poucos dias instalei o Fededora 24, com tudo concluído instalei o Ionic e Cordova, e logo depois o JDK. Ao dá o seguinte comando `ionic build android` eu verifiquei que faltava o SDK, instalei normalmente, porem ao executar o comando novamente eu obtive o seguinte erro:

```html
You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.

Running command: /home/omestre/IonicProjects/ionicTask/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /home/omestre/IonicProjects/ionicTask


add to body class: platform-android

Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.
```

Já tentei altera o meu arquivo `bashrc` e nada resolve, segue como está o arquivo:

```html
# .bashrc

# User specific aliases and functions

alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

export NVM_DIR="/root/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm

export PATH=$PATH:/Android/Sdk/tools:/opt/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:/Android/Sdk/tools/bin
export PATH=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/home/omestre/.local/bin:/home/omestre/bin:/Android/Sdk/tools:/An$
export PATH=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/home/omestre/.local/bin:/home/omestre/bin:/Android/Sdk/tools:/An$
export PATH=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/home/omestre/.local/bin:/home/omestre/bin:/opt/Android/Sdk/tools$
export PATH=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/home/omestre/.local/bin:/home/omestre/bin:/Android/Sdk/tools:/op$
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/Android/Sdk/tools:/opt/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:/opt/Android/Sdk/tools/bin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução foi, no terminal da o seguinte comando:
`nano ~/.bashrc`

Substitui as quatro ultimas linhas por:

`export ANDROID_HOME=/<installation location>/android-sdk-linux
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools`

Ctrl + x para salvar e reiniciar a sessão para as novas configurações serem reconhecidas